# Can't vi in single user mode

Tags: environment-variables, dragonflybsd

In DragonflyBSD, I need to edit `/etc/rc.conf` in single user mode, but

```
# mount -u /
# mount -a  
# vi /etc/rc.conf  
vi: unknown: unknown terminal type  
# ee /etc/rc.conf  
Error opening terminal: unknown.  
# mc
The TERM environment variable is unset!
```

Any hints?

Comment: `export TERM=vt100` and try again, or the location of your termcap definitions are on an unmounted drive (/usr?)

Comment: If you only need to make minor changes you can interactively use `ed`, or non-interactiveyly use `sed`.

Comment: Yay! `export TERM=vt100` did the job. Thanks, Drav.  
And thanks to Robert. Now I want to learn about `ed` an `sed`.

Comment: @DSBP Please add your solution as an answer. So others can benefit from your work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export TERM=vt100` did the job.